# Grammar: "I know right"

Tags: grammaticality, colloquialisms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “I know, right?” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2470/what-does-i-know-right-mean)

Is the expression "I know right" grammatically correct? I hear it a lot and I think I understand what it means, but it just sounds wrong to me.

Comment: What do you think is wrong with it? The choice of words, the tense (I knew right), the 'right: "I know" by itself is OK)? Actually, what do you think 'I know right' actually is supposed to mean?

Comment: See [this related question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2470/what-does-i-know-right-mean).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you're referring to is usually spelled:

> I know, right?

There are two parts here. The first, *I know*, is an ordinary declarative sentence, indicating that the speaker agrees with or supports the other person's assertion. The following *right* is a kind of conversational invitation to agreement. When you end a sentence with *right* (using rising question intonation), it indicates that you expect the person you're talking with to confirm your statement:

> They bought a house, right? (Expects the answer *yes*.)
>
> You're not going to the store, right? (Expects the answer *no*.)

This usage of *right* as a kind of tag-question is colloquial, but not grammatically incorrect. It can be freely used in speech, but should usually be avoided in writing.

Comment: well, yeah the examples you mentioned makes sense. but when you say `I know` you are already agreeing with whatever the person said. then you say "right?" which is sounds unnecessary because you are agreeing with him, so why are would you ask for his agreement? arghh its so hard for me to explain. English is not my mother tounge

Comment: @Mel, I suggest you read [this related question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2470/what-does-i-know-right-mean), as suggested by Peter Shor.

Comment: JSB, what is the meaning of the boxes in your screen name?

Comment: @EugeneSeidel, it's Glagolitic. You might not have font support for it.