# Shorter way of saying "I find this funny because it happens all the time in my life"

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm trying to find a way to say that I find some cartoons funny because they accurately reflect situations that happen all the time in my life.

I considered:

- "hit the spot", but I think it means more "fills a need" as opposed to "reflects the situation".
- "hit home", but that seems to have more of a serious connotation than what I'm looking for

Comment: *The cartoons are funny, because they are reflective of my own experiences?*

Comment: [***I know, right?!***](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2470/what-does-i-know-right-mean)

Comment: Not a perfect fit, but I kind of like "Sarah Kay, Sarah Kay".

Comment: @HotLicks What is "Sarah Kay, Sarah Kay"?

Comment: @dmr - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xZbKHDPPrrc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could say the cartoons [**strike a chord**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/strike+a+chord):

> 1. create an emotional response
>
> *"The music struck a chord with the listeners"*
>
> resonate, come across - be received or understood
>
> 2. refer to or be relevant or familiar to
>
> "I hope this message hits home!"
>
> hit home, strike a note, strike home
>
> impress, strike, affect, move - have an emotional or cognitive impact
>   upon; *"This child impressed me as unusually mature"*; *"This behavior
>   struck me as odd"*
>
> 3. evoke a reaction, response, or emotion
>
> *"this writer strikes a chord with young women"*; *"The storyteller touched a chord"*
>
> touch a chord
>
> arouse, elicit, evoke, provoke, enkindle, kindle, fire, raise - call
>   forth (emotions, feelings, and responses); "arouse pity"; "raise a
>   smile"; "evoke sympathy"

Answer (score 1):

You could say I find it funny because I can identify with it.

Comment: Well it’s true, 15 syllables *is* shorter than 16 syllables.